# Hung Process Debugging

Tags: c

I have a process which is hung and in proc/sysrq-trigger output I see call stack stuck up at:

```
test_code         S 0000000101fcf430     0 15181      1         15182 15180 (NOTLB)
ffff810080997d28 0000000000200086 0000000000000006 0000000000000009 
ffff81012a8a0a28 ffff81012a8a07d0 ffff81010003b980 000079a97155a4a6 
0000000000001474 000000022a8a0808 

Call Trace:
<ffffffff802f3618>{schedule_timeout+30}
<ffffffff8014c1ef>{get_futex_key+71} <ffffffff80149a88>{add_wait_queue+21}
<ffffffff8014c597>{futex_wait_abstime+565}
<ffffffff8010a1da{do_notify_resume+180}
ffffffff8012d7d5>{default_wake_function+0} <ffffffff8014c9c7>{do_futex+104}
<ffffffff801886a7>{pwrite+328} <ffffffff8015692e>{compat_sys_futex+186}
<ffffffff801234b0>{sysenter_do_call+27}
```

Strace shows process stuck up at:

```
[pid  7867] accept(12,  <unfinished ...>
```

Is there any good link I can read on the function in the call stack and debug the issue?

Comment: This is entirely normal, accept() is suppose to "hang" until somebody connects to the port.

Comment: thanks hans for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in [accept (2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) it's not hanging, it's waiting for an incoming connection.

Comment: What about the output of proc/sysrq-trigger output where it is showing some wait on get_futex_key?
What does that mean?